# "Empty" areas for me to add in an adventuring hub near the Sword Coast?

Tags: dnd-5e, campaign-development, forgotten-realms

My setting is going to be near the 5e Sword Coast.  My story is that the Sundering has brought back a creator race from Abeir, and I want them to have a presence south of what used to be Maztica on the western continent of Faerun.  I don't think that area was developed, so I'm going to add in my own homebrew area there.

I'd like to start the adventurers in a town that appeared on the Sword Coast after the Sundering.  My story is that the town was either veiled by magics and the Sundering lifted the illusion, or that the town actually was brought in from Abeir.  I'll probably go with the latter since the style of the town is Moroccan/Gypsy.  It was a port town, but now lies tens of miles from the sea and has to reinvent itself as a center of education and training in the arts and magic - new things to Toril that this town can capitalize upon.

Is there a good location for this town to exist, or for my progenitor race to exist that hasn't been developed?  Have I already chosen good areas?  I know Sembia used to be a huge, undeveloped area for homebrew adventures, but that has changed and I'd like to know of other places that are still left to the imagination.

Thanks

Comment: Questions about "good ideas" are too broad - suggest you delete these and focus on what is answerable

Comment: I don't believe I was asking for "good ideas".  I asked if the areas I selected, as far as anyone may know, are undeveloped in the lore of Faerun/Forgotten Realms so that I can fully explore my homebrew locales in those areas OR if there's a area better served for such a use.

Comment: [Related] [What about the areas without description in the Forgotten Realms?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/55316)

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, but I've read in a previous post that Sembia was such a place until relatively recently.  It has been more fleshed out with locales and personalities over the years.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem coming up with an area in Faerun that I could confirm wasn't already detailed in some other publication, not wanting to conflict with canonical lore that has been previously established.  To work around this, I decided on using the current events of the 5e game to my advantage.

The **Sundering**, that is the joining of Abeir and Toril, has allowed me to take liberties in adding my own areas to previously explored lands with the justification that they were shunted over from Abeir.  This makes the areas I'm using mysterious and unexplored once again, even though they're right in the Sword Coast region.

I am looking at Anchorome, Osse and Katashaka for future homebrew areas since I believe their lore hasn't been established.  Even so, the **Sundering** allows for a lot of DM discretion.

Thanks, and happy gaming.